# Ajax error in Wordpress load more?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have try to load option for my custom page template, Ajax return undefined error After click load more button.

Custom blog page

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
      <section id="posts">
        <?$postslist = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'order'          => 'ASC'
    ) );

    if ( $postslist ) {
        foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
            setup_postdata( $post );
            ?>
            <div style='color:#000'>
                   <?php echo '<br>'.$post->ID.'->'; the_title(); ?>

            </div>
        <?php
        endforeach; 
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } ?>
      </section>
      <?php if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
        <nav class="load_more">
          <?php next_posts_link( 'Load More' ); ?>
        </nav>

      <?php endif;  ?>
    <?php endif;  ?>


    <div class="load_more"><a>list</a></div>
```

Custom js

```
jQuery('.load_more a').live('click', function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
              jQuery('.load_more').html('<span class="loader">Loading More Posts...</span>');
              $.get(link, function(data) {
                  var post = $("#posts .post ", data);
                  $('#posts').append(post);
              });
              jQuery('.load_more').load(link+' .load_more a');
          });
```

Ajax Error:

GET http://kannan.test.dev/blog/

200 OK
        398ms
jquery....=1.11.1 (line 4)
GET http://kannan.test.dev/blog/undefined

404 Not Found
        321ms
jquery....=1.11.1 (line 4)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://kannan.test.dev/blog/undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get the url by accessing the `href` attribute in your jQuery function, but you're not supplying it, that's why the url has `undefined` appended at the end.

You need to set your "href" attribute here

```
<div class="load_more"><a href='...'>list</a></div>
```

in order for this line of code to work:

```
var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
```